# python, Selenium "CTRL+S" to save video not working

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I've tried to formulate it in various ways and nothing works.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

path = "c:\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)

driver.get("https://www.tiktok.com/@mrpianoman/video/6962623261184167173?lang=en&is_copy_url=1&is_from_webapp=v1")

video_link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".video-card-one-column.default video").get_attribute("src")
driver.get(video_link)

action = ActionChains(driver)
action.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys("S").key_up(Keys.CONTROL)
```

Once it opens the video's direct-link, normally I would just press CTRL+S to save the video, but the script can't do it for some reason.

Comment: "the script can't do it for some reason." what exactly goes wrong? Is there some error? Does it just not work? If the latter, how are you confirming it doesn't work?

When I follow your code to get to that URL, the press CTRL+S, it opens a dialogue to download a file. Perhaps that's where you are running into trouble?

Comment: @C.Peck Sorry, I wasn't clear. Nothing happens on the screen. There's no error, but it doesn't prompt me to download/save anywhere as you're suggesting.

Comment: After the `.perform()` added, can you try adding some sleep of second or 2 between `driver.get(video_link)` and the sending CTRL+S?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I think I know what the problem is. Or at least, *a* problem with your script. The ActionChains won't do anything unless you add a `.perform()`. Try your code like this

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

path = "c:\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)

driver.get("https://www.tiktok.com/@mrpianoman/video/6962623261184167173?lang=en&is_copy_url=1&is_from_webapp=v1")

video_link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".video-card-one-column.default video").get_attribute("src")
driver.get(video_link)

action = ActionChains(driver)
action.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys("S").key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

If that doesn't work next thing I'd try is to add a wait before the action to make sure the content is loaded when it's executed. Just adding `time.sleep(3)` or whatever would work to test it out.

Comment: Nice catch, I forgot .perform(), but unforunately both solutions don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending CTRL+S with `ActionChains` please try downloading the video as following:
If you are using Python 2:

```
import urllib
...
video_link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".video-card-one-column.default video").get_attribute("src")
urllib.urlretrieve(video_link, 'videoname.mp4')
```

For Python 3:

```
import urllib.request
...
video_link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".video-card-one-column.default 
urllib.request.urlretrieve(video_link, 'videoname.mp4')
```

Comment: It gives me: urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden.